# Mysql Rename Multiple tables with a pattern

Tags: mysql, rename, multiple-tables

I know how to run

```
RENAME TABLE onetable_test TO onetable;
```

But is there a method to rename many tables with a pattern and don't write a lot of code like

```
RENAME TABLE onetable_test TO onetable;
RENAME TABLE twotable_test TO twitable;
RENAME TABLE threetable_test TO threetable;    
...
```

I am using mysql.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be beyond the scope of your question but you could write a script to dump the list of tables, do the match in your script and then execute the `RENAME`s.

Comment: Assume I can write a script to get the list of those table names, then what I do? Could u explain more about it? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use below stored procedure ::

```
DELIMITER $$
```

CREATE

```
PROCEDURE `Rename_Tables`()

BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE newTableName VARCHAR(70);
DECLARE t_query VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE '%table_test' AND table_schema='test' ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO tableName;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET newTableName = SUBSTRING(tableName, 1,LOCATE('_',tableName)-1);
    SET t_query = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', tableName, ' TO ', newTableName);

    SET @myQuery = t_query;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @myQuery;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END LOOP;

END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

Replace table_schema with your table_schema name.

Comment: +1 For well explained and formatted answer. Welcome to the community.Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
select group_concat(v.name SEPARATOR ' ') 
from (
      select concat('rename table ', t.table_name, ' to ', substring(reverse(v.name), instr(reverse(v.name), '_') + 1, length(v.name)) name 
      from information_schema.tables t
      where 
          table_schema = 'put_your_table_schema'
          and table_name like '%_test'
     ) v;
```

1. Running this query will return script that should be executed to rename tables.
2. `substring(reverse.....)` rather than simple `replace(v.name, '_test', '')` used because we need to be sure that we will replace only `_test` occurrences only at the end of the string.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification on @ravnur's answer:

```
SET group_concat_max_len=5000;
SELECT group_concat(v.name separator '; ')
FROM (
    SELECT concat('RENAME TABLE ', t.table_name, ' TO ', replace(t.table_name, 'wp_', 'blog_')) name
    FROM information_schema.tables t
    WHERE table_name like 'wp_%'
) v;
```

Useful when you want to rename your Wordpress tables from the default prefix of `wp_` to `blog_` (for example). Copy and paste the output of that command into the mysql shell or phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update what worked for me since this post is pretty old. I needed to add the ` mark before and after the table names. And don't forget to add the last ; because this can sometimes throw a syntax error.

```
SET group_concat_max_len=5000;
SELECT group_concat(v.name separator '; ')
FROM (
    SELECT concat('RENAME TABLE `', t.table_name, '` TO `', replace(t.table_name, 'wp_', 'wplocal_'), '`') name
    FROM information_schema.tables t
    WHERE table_name like 'wp_%'
) v;
```