# Replace a partial string in table name+mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have the tables name like `xyz_table1`, `xyz_table2`...

I want to replace the `xyz` with some certain string like `abc`.

So table name will be like `abc_table1`, `abc_table2`...

If I want to rename the table name with `RENAME TABLE`, then I will have to write `RENAME TABLE` script for all the table. If there are more than 300 table then it's kind too much manual work, i.e. I will have to write the `RENAME TABLE` script for all the table.
So there is other way to replace the partial string in table name?

Comment: Try to use stored procedure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642020/mysql-rename-multiple-tables-with-a-pattern

Comment: @shin:: Thank you for your reply. I am asking for the one liner sql script for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can run concat on information schema table:

you can check it output

```
select concat("alter table " . TABLE_NAME . " to " .replace(TABLE_NAME , "xyz", "abc"). ";") from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA="database_name" ;
```

and after you can run it :

```
mysql --batch --skip-column-names --execute \
'select concat("alter table " . TABLE_NAME . " to " .replace(TABLE_NAME , "xyz", "abc"). ";") 
 from information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA="database_name"' | mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follow,
`

```
1) show tables.
2) copy all the table names.
3) paste it in an excel sheet.
4) apply formula for creating a rename query and drag it to apply for remaining 300 tables.
5) copy the queries and run.`
```

it will take 2-3 minutes. that's it.